# XML parsing issue in Python using xml.etree or Dom API

Tags: python, xml

I have following simple code that is parsing a XML file.
The issue is if in XML file the name space contains ":" i get an error. Not having  it, no issue.  It happens when i have ":" between "Junos and Style" when i remove the ":" from XML it works perfectly.
Please advise.

**Fail with this:**

```
<interface-information xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/12.1X47/junos-interface" **junos:style**="brief">
```

**Works with This:**

```
<interface-information xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/12.1X47/junos-interface" **junosstyle**="brief">
```

Python Script:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom


DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("test.xml")
collection = DOMTree.documentElement
if collection.hasAttribute("xmlns"):
   print "Root element : %s" % collection.getAttribute("xmlns")

Interfaces = collection.getElementsByTagName("logical-interface")


for rname in Interfaces:
   print "*****Interface*****"
   rtype = rname.getElementsByTagName('name')[0]
   print "Type: %s" % rtype.childNodes[0].data
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 48, in <module>
    DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("test.xml")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1921, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 924, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(fp)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
    parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: unbound prefix: line 2, column 0
```

It works not having ":" in XML between "Junos and Style"

Here is complete XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<interface-information xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/12.1X47/junos-interface" junos:style="brief">
<logical-interface>
<name>reth4.10</name>
<description>
Test description
</description>
<if-config-flags>
<iff-snmp-traps/>
<internal-flags>
0x0
</internal-flags>
</if-config-flags>
<encapsulation>
ENET2
</encapsulation>
<filter-information>
</filter-information>
<logical-interface-zone-name>
Test2
</logical-interface-zone-name>
<allowed-host-inbound-traffic>
<inbound-ping/>
</allowed-host-inbound-traffic>
<address-family>
<address-family-name>
inet
</address-family-name>
<interface-address>
</interface-address>
</address-family>
<address-family>
<address-family-name>
multiservice
</address-family-name>
</address-family>
</logical-interface>
</interface-information>
```

Comment: Assuming you are trying to parse a response. Can you paste the complete xml ? I tried the following sample response and it worked fine http://pastebin.com/peJVU6Zj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the definition for ***junos*** apparently resolves the parsing issue.

```
<rpc-reply xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/12.1X47/junos">
```

I have used the following working sample for [reference](http://pastebin.com/peJVU6Zj).

Answer (score 1):

Just found what the issue is.

I had to define xmlns:junos in XML.

Don't know why but somehow i had omitted this line in my XML. I think it happened while i was copy pasting the XML.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Yeah please go ahead.